# Why is the combination of a $watch, a promise and ng-options behaving differently in angularJS 1.3?

Tags: angularjs, promise, watch, ng-options

After upgrading from angularJS 1.2 to 1.3 I have an issue with ng-options. The selected value is not shown in the browser.

[image]

I've got an HTML select:

```
<select ng-model="selectedField" ng-options="field for field in fields"></select>
```

After setting the selectedField and loading the fields (via a promise) with angularJS 1.2 it works fine.
However with angularJS 1.3 the selected value is not shown.

Changing the ng-options query by using the "track by" option makes it work in angularJS 1.3 again.

```
<select ng-model="selectedField" ng-options="field for field in fields track by field"></select>
```

I discovered this by coincidence. In this case the "track by" should not be needed as fields is a list of strings. And selectedField is a string as well. So the default comparison used by ng-options should work.

This works but I'm not happy. It does not make sense and I need a solution I understand.

I continued my examination of this issue and I found out that using a $watch that uses a promise to load data into the $scope.fields is the "toxic" combination.

- If I call the promise directly from the controller then it works fine in angularJS 1.3.
- If I bind the list of values in the $watch then it works fine as well.
- If I use both ($watch and promise) it breaks.

Show me the code!
http://plnkr.co/edit/a58Nd61TNI3G4L7GQZ5l?p=preview

In Plunker there are three cases:

- Case 1: only promise and ng-options works fine in 1.3
- Case 2: Only $watch and ng-options works fine in 1.3
- Case 3: $watch, promise and ng-options does not work in 1.3

And to mention again: all cases work fine if I add the "track by" option. Or use angularJS 1.2.

Can anybody explain me why case 3 is not working anymore when using angularJS 1.3.
Using the "track by" looks like a hack in this case and it doesn't feel right.
And above all I like to understand my code is working like it is!

Good observation by Blazemonger: Two options are selected="selected":

[image]

In both selects two values are selected.

But what (in angular 1.3?) is causing this?

Comment: All cases works for me, at least in your Plunker.

Comment: @Blackhole note - not working means that the first dropdown does not have the correct default value selected. I can reproduce this.

Comment: Not correct indeed means that first dropdown is not showing the selected value. If you use choose case 2.1 or case 2.2 make sure the line beneath case 1 is commented out again.

Comment: I notice in the DOM inspector that in case 2.1, **two** options are `selected="selected"`, but in case 1 and 2.2, only one option is.

Comment: Just checked what happens when using angularJS 1.2: also two values selected in the HTML select. But then (at least?) the browser is showing the expected selected value. Weird.

Comment: note that if you let the dom get the normal behaviour ( with out default value ) the element selected is always the first element no matter the field that is selected..

Comment: I insist, I'm on Firefox and everything's fine.

Comment: @Blackhole thx. In Firefox indeed no issue. Just checked it myself. IE and Chrome however having troubles.